# Angular ngFor not displaying changed array

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ngfor, angular-gridster2

in my application I have a Dashboard where the user can add and delete widgets. To do so I am using angular-gridster2. This works well, but when I am adding or deleting a widget from the dashboard first no widgets are displayed anymore and then only after a refresh the correct changes occur. My Widget list the ngFor directive is iterating through is build from an observable. These values change correctly.

This is my html:

```
<gridster #dashboardgrid [options]="options" class="widget-container">
    <gridster-item *ngFor="let widget of widgetList()" (mouseup)="setCurrentWidgetId(widget.id)" [item]="widget.position" class="gridster-design drag-handler">
      <!-- some stuff-->
    </gridster-item>
</gridster>
```

In my `ngOnInit` I am subscribing from the observable:

```
    this.dataService.currentDashboardId.subscribe(dashboardId => this.currentDashboardId = dashboardId);
    this.dataService.currentSheetId.subscribe(sheetId => this.currentSheetId = sheetId);
    this.dataService.projectData
      .subscribe((project: Project) => {
        this.project = project;
  });
```

And this is the method returning the `list of widgets` which should be displayed:

```
    widgetList(): Array<Widget> {
    return this.project.dashboards
      .find(x => x.id === this.currentDashboardId).sheets
      .find(x => x.id === this.currentSheetId).widgets;
  }
```

I really can't find the reason for this behaviour so if anybody does I appreciate that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try using a custom trackby function, did you try it ?

Comment: Keep your widgetList() under ngOnInit(), store return value to a list and use that list with *ngFor. This way you are iterating just a return value of a function that is why it is not reflecting on update.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to debug it? 
Try to change the foreach loop to a list, instead of a function

```
*ngFor="let widget of widgetList()"

*ngFor="let widget of list"
```

and in your ngOnInit:

> this.list = this.widgetList()

this way you can debug it and see if your list contains any items. If it does, then I would look deeper into your gridster-item component and make sure that the 
`[item]="widget.position"` has value according to the component logic

Answer (score 0):

store the array in some variable let say widgetList

```
widgetList : any;
widgetList(): Array<Widget> {
return this.widgetList = this.project.dashboards
  .find(x => x.id === this.currentDashboardId).sheets
  .find(x => x.id === this.currentSheetId).widgets;
}
```

and use ngfor in html like this

```
*ngFor="let widget of widgetList"
```